# Keep current .vmoptions updated automatically while using JetBrains toolbox?

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

The old `.vmoptions` file is located here:

> /Users/patmyron/Library/Application
> Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/172.4343.14/IntelliJ IDEA
> CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions

After updating through JetBrains toolbox, the new `.vmoptions` file is here:

> /Users/patmyron/Library/Application
> Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/173.4127.27/IntelliJ IDEA
> CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions

It is tedious to remember and manually edit the new `.vmoptions` file after every update because JetBrains does not automatically inherit your edited settings from the old to the new `.vmoptions` file.

Is there any way to automatically sync your settings from your old `.vmoptions` file to your new `.vmoptions` file after every update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See the FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869). You just don't edit this file inside the install location, but in the config directory using `Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options**.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Follow up: is there any way to edit values like -Xms across all of the IDEs at once?

Comment: @PatMyron no, the options are per IDE.